# UI -> WebAPI Controller -> Services Pattern

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I've been learning about writing WebApi design patterns.

I am trying to create a simple CRUD web app with ReactJS UI and C# .NET CORE webapi with sql backend.

Articles show that specific Repositories are a direct reflection of the tables inside the DAL.  And the services layer handles the domain objects and draws entities from the repositories layer.  Those same articles also show the controller being designed for changing entities from just one data table in the DAL.  So basically, an Employees table inside the DAL would have an Employees Service and an Employees Controller.  Is this the correct interpretation?

In my example:
I am confused about which path is the proper way to do it.
I have a form that needs to get, post, put records from two different tables (Employees and Devices) in the DAL.

So do I build a single controller that can handle this form's requests (with JSON obj) or do I build two controllers and code the UI to speak to two separate controllers (one for each table)?

In this example, I skipped the repository layer because there's not much logic to need both a repository and service layer.

Please see the two alternative diagrams:

| Multiple Controllers | Single Controller |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Multiple Controllers] | [image: Single Controller] |

Comment: Is there no best practice pattern for this scenario?  Or conversely, is there no dead wrong practice?

Comment: Maybe this question is best suited to SoftwareEngineering.

Comment: @Klau This may help:https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162399/how-essential-is-it-to-make-a-service-layer the tldr version is design the controller to services pattern is subjective as long as you are using the services for what they are intended for. What may work for one organization/person/group may not be the best for all scenarios but if you are just using a service layer for the sake of using a service layer I would say that's a bad practice.